# Apply css on :host dynamically

Tags: css, polymer

How can I dynamically apply css on my element(:host) if condition == true?

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
   <template>
        <style>
           :host{
             display: block;
           }
        </style>
    .......
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to accomplish this. One of the easiest ways is to use [Conditional Template Binding](https://www.polymer-project.org/docs/polymer/binding-types.html#conditional-templates). There's a lot of useful information in there. Very worth checking out.

```
<polymer-element name="my-element">
    <template>
        <template if="{{condition}}">
            <style> Style set 1 </style>
        </template>
        <template if="{{condition2 OR !condition}}">
            <style> Style set 2 </style>
        </template>
        ....
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

Comment: That is simple and beatifull. Just changed my ugly code to this. My only idea was to apply css like this `this.style.*`.

Comment: I use it for a lot of things. Simplifies a lot. Be sure to check out all of the other Template Bindings... Lots of fun.